# How do I get an error in the device Orientation?

Tags: flutter

I Know This's Very Basic, But I Do Not Know How To Do It
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I had to define device orientation in the set Page widget

```
Widget setPage(){
final deviceOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
switch(currentindex){
  case 0:
    return buildHome();
 //   break;
  case 1:
    return deviceOrientation == Orientation.portrait ? buildPicture() : buildPicturel();
//   break;
  case 2:
    return buildVideo();
//   break;
  case 3:
    return buildSearch();
 //   break;
  case 4:
    return buildProfile();
 //   break;
  default: return buildHome();

}
```

}

Comment: Please stop using screenshots to show your code, this is not reproducible and can as well lead to a situation that the image will be removed by time by the image hosting provider. Your Q/A will lose all its meaning, please edit it and provide code instead.

Comment: Ok, from now on, I will write the code in the question and thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

You defined your **deviceOrientation** variable inside the build method instead of inside the Widget itself. So, you can't access **deviceOrientation** variable from 'setPage' function. You should pass **deviceOrientation** value to function.